# Deleted a Logical Volume to free space - Ubuntu still looks for it on bootup - need help

Tags: 16.04, boot, mount, raid, lvm

In an attempt to free up some space on my Home media server, I deleted a Logical Volume from a Raid 5 Array (MDADM).  Now when booting, Ubuntu fails to load due to a timeout trying to mount the deleted LV.

Running Ubuntu Server 16.04

There is another LV on the same Volume Group which mounts fine.

In recovery mode, I can see everything load OK and mount ok (including the other LV thats on the same VG), and then it tries to mount the Logical Volume I deleted earlier (called Backup) and it times out, causing the boot to fail.

I am then dropped into "Recovery Mode" which then promptly breaks and I get the message "Welcome to emergency mode!".

When scrolling through the results of "journalctl -xb" I eventually see the following:

> Jun 13 19:09:05 ubuntunas kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
>   Jun 13 19:09:05 ubuntunas systemd[1]: dev-DataVolume-Backup.device: Job dev-DataVolume-Backup.device/start timed out.
>   Jun 13 19:09:05 ubuntunas systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-Dataolume-Backup.device.
>   --Subject: Unit dev-DataVolume-Backup.device has failed
>   --Defined-By: systemd

There are a variety of other messages which imply that loading this LV is a "dependency"...

Any suggestions on how to correct?  I am not very strong technically, so I very much appreciate any help.

Thanks!
JonNoob

Comment: Is there mention of it in `/etc/fstab` (file system table) that you didn't remove/delete?

Comment: Yes - fstab still lists it.  After backing it up under a different name, I removed that line and it's booting up properly now - looks corrected.  Anything I should check (logs etc ) to confirm there aren't any other issues?  Thanks!